# Get Nashorn JsonObject in Java

Tags: java, javascript, json, nashorn

In my JavaScript I have a JSON Object which I use as a parameter of a Java object. On the Java side I receive a `jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO4` but only the `jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO` class exits. How can I access this JSON Object?

```
var test = {
    "id": 10,
    "Hello": "World",
    "test": {
        "Lorem" : "Ipsum",
        "java"  : true
    }
}

m.call(test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some google searches i found a solution: On the Java side, I must use a `java.util.Map`. So I can parse this Map to an `org.json.simple.JSONObject`

```
public void call(Map map){
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(map); // convert map to an json Object
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using ScriptObjectMirror:

```
public void call(ScriptObjectMirror obj) {
    System.out.println(obj.get("Hello"));
}
```

See this article for more examples: http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/

Comment: More valid than marked answer indeed. `ScriptObjectMirror` implements `Bindings` which implements `Map<String,Object>` which explains why Map is also valid. Obviously `ScriptObjectMirror` is way more powerful in JS related features of the object, but if Map is all someone needs... ;-)